# Java compare two Dates Year, month and day

Tags: java, date, compare

I have a method to compare two dates to see if transactionDate is in range between validFrom and validUntil, validFrom and validUnti has value like "2017-01-01 00:00:00" but the transaction date sometimes comes with different hours due to conversion to different timezone.

```
public boolean isDateWithinEmploymentDeploymentValidityPeriod(Date transcationDate, Parameter parameter) {
    return transcationDate.compareTo(parameter.getValidFrom()) >= 0
            && (parameter.getValidUntil() == null || transcationDate.compareTo(parameter.getValidUntil()) <= 0);
}
```

So i need to compare compare only Year Month and day and don't take time into account, what would be most efficient way without transforming date to gregorianCalendar and geting year month and day separately?

Comment: Careful: you need to do the transformation in a specific time zone in order to get the date fields. `Date` has no timezone.

Comment: What are validFrom and validUntil? Dates? Strings? What's wrong with the code you posted (assuming you just forgot to paste `compareTo` in `transcationDate.(parameter.getValidUntil())`?

Comment: What's wrong is that i shouldn't acummulate hours when comparing, it shouldn't depend on timezone, so for example if validUntil is "2017-03-01 00:00:00" and transactionDate comes "2017-03-01 10:00:00" i should return true that it's in valid period, validUntil and validFrom is Date objects

Comment: I am not sure I understand your reasoning taken into account the example in your last comment. `validUntil` is the upper bounds of your date period, isn't it? Then why should it return `true` with a date that is posterior to it? Or it's just a typo, maybe? Also, which version of Java are you using?

Comment: @klehelley he only wants to consider year, month and day and ignore the others. That's why he is returning true.

Comment: Ah right, for a moment I kind of forgot about that. The worse part being that I removed what I initially wrote at the end of my comment because it was about the full date and not just the 'date' part.

Comment: I'm using JAVA 8 by the way.

Comment: Good, so we can have something that works without too much code using `java.time.LocalDate`. I'll prepare an answer using it. :D

Answer (score 2):

## `LocalDate`

I think the easy solution is to convert to `LocalDate`:

```
LocalDate validFrom = LocalDate.parse("2017-01-01 00:00:00", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
```

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class [accepts parsing with a pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-) that includes hours, minutes and seconds, it just ignores those values from the string.

Do the same with `validUntil` and the transaction date. Compare the resulting `LocalDate` instances using [`isBefore()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#isBefore-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate-), [`isAfter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#isAfter-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate-), [`isEqual()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#isEqual-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate-), or [`compareTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#compareTo-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate-).

Answer (score 2):

If you were using Java < 8, unfortunately there would have been no simple answer (i.e. you'd have to use `Calendar` as you said in your question, or maybe rely on a third-party library like Joda-Time).

Hopefully you use Java 8, so we can leverage the goodness that is the `java.time` package. Since you want to just compare dates (not times), and do not care about timezones, what you want to use is `java.time.LocalDate`.

```
// Ideally, instances of the java.time classes are used throughout
// the application making this method useless.
private LocalDate toLocalDate(Date date) {
    return LocalDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
}

public boolean inRange(Date date, Date from, Date until) {
    return inRange(toLocalDate(date), toLocalDate(from), toLocalDate(until));
}

public boolean inRange(LocalDate date, LocalDate from, LocalDate until) {
    return !date.isBefore(from) && !date.isAfter(until);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Calendar and set the other parameters apart from year, month and day to 0.

```
Calendar transactionCalendar= Calendar.getInstance();

Date transactionDate = ...;

transactionCalendar.setTime(transactionDate );
transactionCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
transactionCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
transactionCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
transactionCalendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```